# Project: CSS Grid Boxes

Tags: css

I am trying out this grid experiment. Here's the problem, we're attempting to get the bottom box to fill in about 90% or better. In the future, I might do just the same with the others too.

What we would like to see is that by expanding this into multiple boxes just like above.

For example the bottom box will be bigger than the second row, and would like it be about 100%.

Can you please assist me?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

 <html><head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <link href="wxsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="wrap">

 <div class="grid" > 
  <div class="row"> 
 <div class="image"> 
 <img src="images/photo1.jpg" alt="A Lily" /> 
 <p>A lily in the gardens of The Vyne Country House</p> 
 </div> 

 </div> 
 <div class="row"> 
 <div class="image"> 
 <img src="images/photo2.jpg" alt="A crazy looking Allium flower" />
 <p>A crazy looking flower</p>
 </div>
 <div class="image">
 <img src="images/photo4.jpg" alt="A Robin sitting on a fence" />
  <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden  
 with us.
 </p>

 <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden with 
 us.
 </p>

 </div>
 <div class="image">

 <img src="images/photo4.jpg" alt="A Robin sitting on a fence" />
 <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden   
 with us. 
 </p>

 <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden 
 with us.
 </p>

 </div>

 <div  class="image">
 <img src="images/photo4.jpg" alt="A Robin sitting on a fence" />
 <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden 
 with us.
 </p>
 <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden with
 us.
 </p>

 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="image" >
 <img src="images/photo4.jpg" alt="A Robin sitting on a fence" / >
 <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden 
 with us.
 </p> 
 </div>  

 <p>
 This robin has been visiting our garden over the summer. 
 He is very friendly and doesn't seem to be too worried about sharing the garden 
 with us.
 </p>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Now for the CSS Section:

```
 /*html layout*/    
 html {
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 background:#a7a09a; 
 color:#000; } 
 #wrap {
 width:780px; 
 margin:0 auto; 
 background:#99c;     
 }

 /*main body*/
 #main {
 float: right;
 height: 64.5em;
 width: 607px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 }
 h2 {margin:0 0 1em;}

 .grid { width:100%;
 display: table; 
 border-spacing: 4px; 
 } 
 .row { 
 display: table-row; 
 } 
 .image { 
 display: table-cell; 
 width: 240px; 
 background-color: #000; 
 border: 8px solid #000; 
 vertical-align: top; 
 text-align: center; 
 } 
 .image p { 
 color: #fff; 
 font-size: 85%; 
 text-align: left;
 padding-top: 8px;
```

The bottom line, is from what I would like to see is the ability to adjust all of my boxes 
to what ever size, height & length.

Thanks, your help is truly appreciated! Have an Nice Weekend!

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to adjust them dynamically, or just set static sizes diferent from the ones you have here?

Comment: If it not to hard to for the asking, could I see a example of either dynamically or static for my own future reference? - Michael Offutt